# Why doesn't it see the variable inside element declaration?

Tags: xslt, marklogic

The following code gives an error:

```
[1.0-ml] XDMP-UNDVAR: (err:XPST0008) Undefined variable $ename
```

However if I change the `xsl:element` to `<xsl:element name="yyyXXX">` it shows that it sees **$ename** in value-of, i.e.

`<yyyXXX>zzz</yyyXXX>`

The stylesheet below works just fine in Saxonica 9.x

Thanks.

---

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

xdmp:xslt-eval(
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:xdmp="http://marklogic.com/xdmp"        
   extension-element-prefixes="xdmp"
    version="2.0">     

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="ename" select="'zzz'"/>
  <xsl:element name="yyy{$ename}">       
   <xsl:value-of select="$ename"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
,document{ <doc/> })
```

Comment: That should have worked. Can you please file a bug report to support at marklogic.com? Unfortunately, I can't think of a work-around.

Comment: I'm using the express version, I don't have a support contract. Yes, looks like a bug to me too.

Comment: I am sure you can still send this bug to them.

Comment: Not a bug. See Justin's answer. The $ename variable is evaluated in the construction of the XSLT stylesheet. You need the double curly braces to insert the literal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need two sets of curly brackets around your element name, e.g. `yyy{{$ename}}`. That tells the outer XQuery to treat those as literal curly brackets in the XSLT. If you were invoking the XSLT from an external document (e.g. with `xdmp:xslt-invoke`) you wouldn't need the extra brackets; this is equivalent to your Saxon test. The ability to evaluate XQuery to dynamically create XSLT is pretty powerful, but does impose a little more cognitive overhead.

Comment: It gets really confusing if you want to output curly braces in the result of processing your embedded XSLT (e.g., to generate another stylesheet). Then you'd have to write *four* curly braces to get one, e.g.: `xdmp:xslt-eval(<element attribute="{{{{bracketed}}}}" xsl:version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" />, <empty/>)` outputs `<element attribute="{bracketed}"/>`

Comment: Yes, it can. That’s one reason why I typically use `xdmp:xslt-invoke` rather than `eval`. (I also don’t generally need to dynamically generate my XSLT.) You get some additional caching on an invoked stylesheet that can’t be done on an `eval`. If need to dynamically generate XSLT, though, `xdmp:xslt-eval` is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for that, works fine now. Gah, that's a nasty gotcha, at least we know now.